# Sony Bluetooth Headset freezing media

Tags: sound, bluetooth, media

I am new to Ubuntu. I have everything else working perfectly on the new OS, however it doesn't seem to work well with my Sony MDR-ZX003BT Bluetooth headset. I can connect just fine and it shows the paired address etc. I've tried toggling between 'Headset HSP/HFP' and 'A2DP sink'. Nothing I do prevents the activated headset from freezing all media applications. Youtube freezes and won't play, hard drive files won't play etc. As soon as I turn them off, everything works fine. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.